# Should we accept tag wiki excerpts with co-tagging guidelines?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

I just approved a tag wiki excerpt addition which, in addition to describing some library, also said: "Apply this tag together with the framework in which whatever-lib is used". ... but then I had second thoughts about whether such guidelines are appropriate for a tag wiki excerpt. Should I have removed that sentence?

Comment: Seems okay to me. Tag wiki excerpts are supposed to guide people on how to use the tag, and if the tag is best combined with others, let's help out that one person who reads it. :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Should we accept tag wiki excerpts with co-tagging guidelines?

Yes we should as long as the co-tagging guidelines make sense and are created in good faith. First of all, tag usages guidance in tag wiki excerpts satisfies (read: does not go against which would warrant removal/rejection) [guideline #4](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tag-excerpts) of the help center article on excerpt editing. it amounts to, I quote:

> Provide basic guidance on when to use the tag.

Secondly, co-tagging advice works towards the goal stated by guideline #1 in that it helps clarify what the questions with a given tag should be about (for example, the excerpt for questions tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) states that they should "include all relevant tags on your question"):

> The excerpt should define the shared quality of questions containing this tag

Finally, specifying which tags should be used with the tag in the excerpt works towards the goal outlined in [Jeff's blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/03/24/redesigned-tags-page) introducing tag excerpts as it helps defining relationships between individual "markings" on the map (think of it like highlighting Commonwealth countries on a world map):

> It is my strong belief that the tags page is an essential map of what your community is, and is not, about.